# How do I make a transparent link over a background jpg in HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css, background, cross-browser, transparent

I've tried all kinds of methods listed in W3schools, all over Google and S.O. and anywhere else, nothing seems to work with this jpg background. There's a portion of the graphic that I want to lay a transparent link over so it becomes clickable. Anything I try makes words at the bottom of the jpg, not over it. I used words within the transparent link so I could see where it was. Please help, I've wasted too much time on this portion of the project in trying to figure this out. I need this in HTML or CSS as they are all I know, so I can adjust it if I need to.

Thanks, Ben.

Comment: Can you provide us with some of the code you were using?

Comment: Look up float and z-index.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just wrap the image in an `<a href="">` element. You won't need anything transparent.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a .jpg file that is set as a background. Part of the background you want to be a link to a separate page. And because the .jpg is set as a background and because you only want part of it to be a link, adding the "a" tag isn't the solution you are looking for?

If that is right I would suggest creating an empty div tag and with css use margins to set it over the part of the background image you want to be a link. You will also probably need to give it a specific width and height to cover the area.

If you do not have it set as an actual background but its inserted with a normal img tag you can use an image map and specify coordinates on the .jpg for a link. w3schools has a good section on it: [Image Map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)